# angular-schema-form redefine schema

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

**Problem:** User selects a country from a selection field an state selection field should change to matching states. E.g.: If selected "Germany", german states should be shown. If "USA" is selected, US states should be shown. This works if user selects a country for the first time. **If user selects an other county, state select field is not updated.**

**Question:** How can I trigger a refresh for that form so it reloads selections, if schema was changed by controller.

**Solution:** Can be achieved with *dependencies*

```
        "country": {
            "required": "true",
            "dataSource": "./run?countries=1",
            "label": "Land:",
            "type": "select"
            }
        },
        "state_de": {
            "required": "true",
            "dataSource": "./run?states=de",
            "label": "Bundesland:",
            "dependencies": {"country": "DE"},
            "signon": {"validator": "countrystate", "ldapattr": "state"},
            "type": "select",
        }
```

in that case German states are only displayed if country was selected to DE.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a $watch function and add js code in the watch  function.